# What's a term for appetite apart from hunger or pathological cause?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

When I see or smell or think of something delicious, I feel a motivation to eat it. I may be hungry or I may be not hungry, it does not matter. Nor do I suffer from pathological polyphagia.

How to describe this kind of appetite in English?

Comment: What's wrong with *appetite*?

Comment: @michael.hor257k As I know of, some other language(Chinese) uses distinct terms for the motivation to eat caused by starving, and for the motivation to eat caused by encountering delicious food. *appetite* does not seem to differentiate these.

Comment: I believe *appetite* is closer to being motivated by some *appetizer* (or other *appetizing* stimulant) than by physical hunger. I am not sure there is a distinct term like the one you describe - except Pavlovian reflex, perhaps.

Comment: @michael.hor257k One has an appetite. One doesn't say I feel an appetite. One feels hunger. One is hungry. One hungers. No, it doesn't make sense, but English doesn't always. There are lots of words for degree of hunger caused by lack of food (peckish, famished, starved, starving), but I .

Comment: @BenAveling How does this contradict what I said?

Comment: @michael.hor257k English is as she is spoke. But I wouldn't rush to describe appetite as a feeling. 
I can't immediately think of a word that means the feeling of hunger motivated by the deliciousness of something. We don't use hunger words, we talk instead in terms of desire: I want that, I'd like that, I'll have that.  And maybe fair enough - such consumption isn't about hunger.

Comment: @BenAveling "*I wouldn't rush to describe appetite as a feeling.*" My dictionary describes it as a *desire* - and it defines *desire* as *a strong feeling*. Anyway, I am still not sure what your point is and how it differs from the one I made earlier.

Comment: @michael.hor257k I'm sure your dictionary is right. Which leaves only that the word appetite isn't specific to appetite caused by deliciously desirable food, and other forms of appetite. Which is what OP asked for.

Comment: I thought I'd go a-looking in the OED for you.  May favourites are: *yapness*, *esurience* and *sharpsetness* although I believe only the middle one of these is neither archaic nor a dielect term.  *Rapaciousness* also springs to mind, and I thought of that one all by myself :)

Comment: When I see or smell or see something delicious, ***I feel compelled to eat it***. I have a compulsion to eat it.

Answer (score 6):

A [**food craving**](https://www.google.com/#q=food+craving+definition) **-** an intense desire to consume a specific food, and is different from normal hunger.

Consider this example:

> I had a sudden **craving** for french fries, so I pulled into the nearest fast-food restaurant.  ([Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/craving))

Craving french fries, for example, means you are hungry for french fries.  However, you probably wouldn't have enough of an appetite to eat something else (like salad.)

Comment: to have a craving for something, yes. to crave something.

Answer (score 0):

**Gustatory**: *Related to or associated with eating or the sense of taste* (Merriam-Webster online).

Strolling through the streets of Paris at dawn is a gustatory delight: the stimulating aroma of coffee mingles irresistibly with the smell of baking bread as local *cafes* and *boulangeries* spring to life in the City of Lights. Paris and its denizens are at breakfast.

Comment: This is not germane here, is it?

Answer (score 0):

> When I see or smell or think of something delicious, I feel [[tempted]](https://www.etymonline.com/word/tempt). I may be hungry or I may be not hungry, it does not matter. Nor do I suffer from pathological polyphagia.

- Eve couldn't resist the **temptation**, she ate the apple.
- I shouldn't, and I'm not even really hungry -- but pecan pralines are so **tempting**, I can't resist.

Answer (score -1):

If you're British, ***[peckish](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/peckish)*** (which Merriam-Webster claims was first used in 1740) fits the bill.

> British   *informal* 
>   [predicative] Hungry.
>
> - ‘And if you get peckish there's a café, which uses organic produce from the farm's garden whenever possible, and a shop which sells organic vegetables, herbs, plants, honey and eggs.’
> - ‘Come lunch time today I found myself feeling really rather peckish but didn't fancy anything cooked.’

It's not full blown hunger, but it can be triggered by seeing a mouthwatering dish, or because lunch or dinner time is drawing near. You are more likely to eat a snack in order to keep these **[*hunger pangs*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/pang)** at bay.

In Italian we have "sentire un certo languorino", one Italian-English online dictionary suggests its English equivalent is: ***[to get the munchies](http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario_inglese/Italiano/L/languorino.shtml)***

> **1.1** **(the munchies)**
>   A sudden strong desire for food.
>    ‘I bought a pork pie to stave off the munchies’
>
> <sub>English Oxford Living Dictionaries</sub>

On the other hand, Wiktionary translates it as [*peckish*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sentire_un_certo_languorino)

While I'm aware that the expression “the munchies” is often used in the cannabis culture, it is *also* used to express that insatiable desire for something sweet or savoury to fill the empty hole feeling we all experience at one time or another.

> **3. the munchies**, Slang. hunger, especially a craving for sweets or snacks:
>   *suffering from the munchies*.
>   <sub>Random House Dictionary, © Random House, Inc. 2018.</sub>

Comment: "The munchies", in my experience, always refers to weed-fueled cravings. You can see this definition in [UD](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Munchies).

Comment: @Laurel does ["the muchies"](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/munchy?s=t) *always* exclude feeling hungry just for the sake of hunger? Oxford and Dictionary.com  seem to disagree with you and the UD.